# Run Bat file Using C#

Tags: c#

I have a bat file having below line

```
cd C:\Program Files\test\design
call open.bat   Proj pswd/XXXXXX /ALL Design
```

I want to run this bat file using C# code.
Please help me out with the code .I have tried couple of code but its not invoking application

```
var t=System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"A:\LogInBat\E3D4.0-Model_40.bat");
```

Comment: var t=System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"A:\LogInBat\E3D4.0-Model_40.bat");

Comment: `A:` commonly refers to a floppydisk drive on windows systems, which barely anyone has these days.

Comment: No it did not worked

Comment: If you type in [Windows]+R and then whatever you pass to Process.Start, does this work as expected?

Comment: No it not invokig but when i open command window and call bat file than it is invoking